# grid css is not working when using Itext's pdfHTML to convert html to pdf

Tags: java, html, css, itext, itext7

Below is HTML

```
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      td {
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-family: "arial";
      }
      .td-grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
      }
      @media print {
        #printButton {
          display: none;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="td-grid">
          <td
            height="15"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#ffaa33"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >Dec</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="15"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#ffaa33"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >Nov</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="15"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#ffaa33"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >Oct</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="15"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#ffaa33"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >Sep</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="15"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#ffaa33"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >Aug</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="15"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#ffaa33"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >Jul</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="15"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#ffaa33"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >Jun</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="15"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#ffaa33"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >May</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="15"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#ffaa33"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >Apr</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="15"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#ffaa33"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >Mar</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="15"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#ffaa33"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >Feb</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="15"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#ffaa33"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >Jan</font
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="td-grid" bgcolor="#fff">
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#fff"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >.</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >0</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
          <td
            height="16"
            width="100%"
            align="center"
            bgcolor="#0d5b0d"
            valign="middle"
          >
            <font size="1" style="font-family: 'verdana'" color="#ffffff"
              >C</font
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Java logic to convert HTML to PDF

```
File f = new File(CB_PDF_FILENAME);
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlString, new FileOutputStream(f));
```

when i open the html in browser its rendering fine with no issue
but after converting that using Itext's pdfHTML to convert html to pdf its messing up the layout in pdf. see attached image

[image: pdf screenshot]

using latest version itextpdf(not commercial)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

am i missing anything? any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Grid CSS is not supported in iText pdfHTML.

Comment: @S_G even i tried without grid with following css same issue.td-grid > td {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8.33% !important;
  max-width: 8.33% !important;
  min-width: 8.33% !important;
}